# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code

Tags: java

How can I call a non static method in main class.I am getting the folowing error in my sample console application

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static method doSomthing() cannot be referenced from a static context
        at sample.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

and the code is,

```
public class Main  {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       doSomthing();
       System.out.print("From Main");
    }

    protected void doSomthing()
    {
        System.out.print("From Main doSomthing");
    }


}
```

Comment: Why would you want to call a non static method from a static one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

problem is you have used non static method in static method which is not allowed in java , change doSomthing() as static method

```
protected static void doSomthing()
{
    System.out.print("From Main doSomthing");
}
```

Or Create an object of Main class and call it

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Main myMain = new Main();
   myMain.doSomthing();
   System.out.print("From Main");
}
```

Comment: thanks.so in a console application all methods should be in static. Is it?

Comment: you can create a object of that class and call your methods not always it should be static.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an *instance* first from your `static` `main` method:

```
new Main().doSomthing();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a **non static** method in main class, unless you instantiate one [Main class].

Comment: or you can change method as static

Comment: author asked "call a non static method"

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Main  {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main main = new Main();
       main.doSomthing();
       System.out.print("From Main");
    }

    protected void doSomthing()
    {
        System.out.print("From Main doSomthing");
    }
}
```