# I use Netbeans 8.2 and mysql query browser 1.1.20.build is successful, an error says incompatible source code

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to get out of this error.Would you mind giving me a hand in here?
Below is my code.

```
package Viewer;

import Model.JDBC;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class home extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    String User;
    Model.JDBC j=new JDBC();

    public home() 
    {
        initComponents();

        User=user;
        Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = t.getScreenSize();
        int w = (int) d.getWidth();
        int h = (int) d.getHeight()-40;
        setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
        jLabel2.setText(new Controler.getDate().date());
        time();
        jLabel3.setText(user);
        ResultSet rs;
        try 
        {
             rs = j.getData("select type from login where username='"+eid+"'");
             if(rs.next())
             {
                if(rs.getString(1).equals("Admin"))
                {
                    home.setEnabled(true);
                    login.setEnabled(true);
                    jr.setEnabled(true);
                    u.setEnabled(true);
                    machine.setEnabled(true);
                    branch.setEnabled(true);
                    emp.setEnabled(true);

                }
                else if(rs.getString(1).equals("Employee"))
                {
                    home.setEnabled(false);
                    login.setEnabled(false);
                    jr.setEnabled(false);                  
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void time() 
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                while (true) 
                {
                String times = new Date().toString();
                String h = times.split(" ")[3];
                jLabel1.setText(h);
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(60);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

   private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
   {                                      
        login ob=new login();
        ob.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
   }                                     

   private void jrActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
   {                                   
        job ob=new job();
        ob.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
   }                                  

   private void uActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
   {                                  
       user ob=new user();
       ob.setVisible(true);
       this.dispose();
   }                                 

  private void machineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
  {                                        
        machine ob=new machine();
        ob.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
  }                                       

  private void empActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
  {                                    
    job ob=new job();
    ob.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
  }                                   

  private void homeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
  {                                     
        home ob=new home();
        ob.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
  }                                    

  private void homeKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
  {                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
  }                               

  private void loginKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
  {                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
  }                                

  private void jrKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
  {                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
  }                             

  private void uKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
  { 
       // TODO add your handling code here:
  }                            

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {

      Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
      expiry.set(2013, 9 , 27,0,0); // Expire at 31 Jan 2010
      Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

      try 
      {
           for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) 
          {
              if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) 
              {
               javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
              }
          }
      } 
      catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
      {
             java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } 
      catch (InstantiationException ex) 
      {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } 
      catch (IllegalAccessException ex) 
      {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } 
      catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
      {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      //</editor-fold>

      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
      {
      public void run() 
      {
        new home().setVisible(true);
      }
   });
}                
}
```

Here is the error that is being displayed when I try to run the thing.

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of type
    at Viewer.home.<init>(home.java:87)
    at Viewer.home$12.run(home.java:389)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Through the above code, I was trying to run the home page of a swing application, where a loading form initiates and then shows up the login form.Everything was quiet fine until I add the code for Login form.Could you please help me with this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is line 87?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173800/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code)

Comment: @e4c5 Yeah. It's  Thread.sleep(60); But I am afraid that it isn't the problem. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @LuFFy I'll look in to that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you have used non static method in static method which is not allowed in java , change all methods as static method Like :

```
public static void time(...
private static void loginActionPerformed(...
private static void jrActionPerformed(...
private static void uActionPerformed(...
private static void machineActionPerformed(...
private static void empActionPerformed(...
private static void homeActionPerformed(...
private static void homeKeyPressed(...
private static void loginKeyPressed(...
private static void jrKeyPressed(...
private static void uKeyPressed(...
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me LuFFy. :) I am afraid that these ActionPerformed and KeyPressed method names are auto generated ones (and non editable I guess ) .